# Почему vs code не реагирует на кнопку "запуск кода"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Вот этот файл запущен в pycharm и vs code. Везде все абсолютно одинаково. Только vs code не реагирует на кнопку пуск. Переустанавливал vs code 2 раза, даже сам пайтон переустанавливал,но ничего.
**Код из vs code**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот скрин из pycharm**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

заранее Спасибо

Comment: Так вы даже не запустили файл на первом скриншоте

Comment: NNL993 запустил,нажал на кнопку запуска кода, но не реагирует никак vs code

Answer (score 0):

Настройку кнопки запуска программы можно посмотреть в параметрах VS Code. Если наведёшь мышь на кнопку запуска, то скорее всего он выведет горячие клавиши, для запуска программы. Например, у меня для запуска нужно нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Ты можешь сам задать сочетание клавиш для запуска файла `.py`
Для этого нужно открыть палитру команд <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, вбить в поиске `Сочетания клавиш`, после написать `Python`. Он выдаст тебе действия и команды, которые можно привязать к горячим клавишам

---

Если же не запускается сам файл, то нужно посмотреть чтобы VS Code правильно находит компилятор Python

Answer (score 0):

Не силен в `PyCharm`, но мне кажется, что проблема в следующем. В VSCode у вас открыта папка, а не проект. Следовательно, интерпретатор для `python` работает глобально. Насколько это критично для вашего запуска не понятно. Но могу сказать, что у вас в проекте я вижу виртуальные пространства (целых два, тоже конфликт в моей голове).

1. пробуйте открыть весь проект целиком в `VSCode`.
2. используйте верный интерпретатор `python` из виртуального пространства (venv). Для выбора используйте <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> -> `Python: Select Interpreter` -> и выберите из списка релевантный для данного окружения.

**UPD**

Нашел на скрине, что в `PyCharm` вы используете `venv1`-окружение. А в `VSCode` не используете. Выберите его как описано в пункте 2.

[Документация на англ](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-python-interpreters) как это осуществить.